# how to access class with the internal keyword inside a third-party jar from kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Speak from technical standpoint of view, whether it is possible to access an internal class inside a third-party jar?

i have try out the '-Xfriend-paths', but it seems it does not support anything like

```
kotlinc -Xfriend-paths=xxxx.jar ...
```

Can any one point me some directions

Comment: `internal` members of 3rd party libraries are not supposed to be accessed by code outside of those libraries. It's `internal` for a reason.

Comment: And of course the entire purpose of the `internal` keyword is to _prevent_ that access.

Answer (score 0):

You may have run into this Kotlin bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29933

Try again using an absolute path, or making sure that your Kotlin version is at least 1.3.70.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to access internal members (which is a good thing). See [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-to-support-package-protected-visibility/1544/2) for more details.